# Updated table title is appended to previous one, rather than replacing it

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a table that is generated with d3.js; when I make a selection in the dropdown menu (for example, "Alaska" rather than the initial/default value, "Alabama"), the title should update.
Although I'm able to get the new title to appear above the table, my problem is that the updated title is appended to the previous one, rather than replacing it.

Here's my plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/7b4CmQqnm3L70QL9FgQD

I've tried moving the code that produces the title outside the final brace `};`, and while this fixes the reduplication problem, this just causes the `selectedState` in the title to remain stuck on "Alabama."

I've also tried revising the `onchange()` function such that it removes the `#title` div in a similar manner as the `table` div is removed when the table gets updated. While this succeeds in removing the `#title` div completely, the new title doesn't get redrawn — it just gets deleted.

I've tried defining the title, or part of it, as a constant. But I just get syntax errors.
Can anyone demonstrate the proper way of updating the title, based on [this Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/7b4CmQqnm3L70QL9FgQD)? I've tried following tutorials for `.enter`, `.update`, and `.exit` but I simply can't grasp how to apply them — or even if they're applicable to my situation.

Comment: Besides the issue described in the question I hope you don't mind if I say that your code has several other problems, from the lack of proper update patterns to async code inside the listeners. When you have a final, working code, I suggest you ask for idiomatic solutions at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, this...

```
div.innerHTML += 'Primary substance use among TEDS aged 12 years and older, by gender, age, race, and ethnicity: ' + selectedState;
```

...is just concatenating any previous text in that `<div>` with the new text.

Instead of that, just assign a new value:

```
div.innerHTML = 'Primary substance use among TEDS aged 12 years and older, by gender, age, race, and ethnicity: ' + selectedState;
```

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qCk4iu51SAtHJ3LzTB27?p=preview